# How to detect when all images are loaded from dynamic page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading another page with images to div. I want to detect when all images are being loaded from dynamically added page.

```
$("#main").load('imagespage.php', function(){
alert("Page loaded");
});
```

This above alerts when page is loaded, not when images loaded. It fires before images are being loaded. Normally, this window onload should work, but it doesnt work if its dynamic loaded page.

```
$(window).load(function() {
 alert("window is loaded including images");
});
```

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: ,Can you add your page code.

Answer (score 0):

You get the *alert("Page loaded");* executed before getting the result of the *$.load* call because the call is setted as asynchronous by default. If you change de behaviour to synchronous, you could do whatever you want to do AFTER getting the result of $.load.

You could try set the behaviour before execute it:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

And afterwards, you can change it again:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

It works on *$.get* and *$.post*, but I never have tried on *$.load*

Answer (score 0):

This should work after all the images are loaded.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    alert("window is loaded including images");
});
```